# Starting gazebo headless over ssh

Tags: ros-kinetic, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello guys,

i have some problems when i try to start gazebo with roslaunch on a pc where i have ssh access.

Its ubuntu 16.04 with ros kinetic.

Here is my launch file:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="world_file"  default="$(env TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE)"/>

  <arg name="base"      value="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_BASE kobuki)"/> <!-- create, roomba -->
  <arg name="battery"   value="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_BATTERY /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0)"/>  <!-- /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0 --> 
  <arg name="gui" default="false"/>
  <arg name="stacks"    value="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_STACKS hexagons)"/>  <!-- circles, hexagons --> 
  <arg name="3d_sensor" value="$(optenv TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR kinect)"/>  <!-- kinect, asus_xtion_pro --> 

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
    <arg name="world_name" value="worlds/Tworld1.world"/>
  </include>
  
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_gazebo)/launch/includes/$(arg base).launch.xml">
    <arg name="base" value="$(arg base)"/>
    <arg name="stacks" value="$(arg stacks)"/>
    <arg name="3d_sensor" value="$(arg 3d_sensor)"/>
  </include>
  
  <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher">
    <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="30.0" />
  </node>
  
  <!-- Fake laser -->
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="laserscan_nodelet_manager" args="manager"/>
<node pkg="depthimage_to_laserscan" type="depthimage_to_laserscan" name="depthimage_to_laserscan">
    <param name="scan_height" value="10"/>
    <param name="output_frame_id" value="/camera_depth_frame"/>
    <param name="range_min" value="0.45"/>
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/depth/image_raw"/>
    <remap from="scan" to="/scan"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

When i start over ssh it only gets to :

```
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead
started roslaunch server http://robolab8:44789/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /bumper2pointcloud/pointcloud_radius: 0.24
 * /cmd_vel_mux/yaml_cfg_file: /opt/ros/kinetic/...
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/output_frame_id: /camera_depth_frame
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/range_min: 0.45
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/scan_height: 10
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency: 30.0
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    bumper2pointcloud (nodelet/nodelet)
    cmd_vel_mux (nodelet/nodelet)
    depthimage_to_laserscan (depthimage_to_laserscan/depthimage_to_laserscan)
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    laserscan_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    mobile_base_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    spawn_turtlebot_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [17081]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 925dced2-fa25-11e8-bbc5-d8cb8a119b1a
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [17094]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [17102]
process[spawn_turtlebot_model-3]: started with pid [17114]
process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-4]: started with pid [17124]
process[cmd_vel_mux-5]: started with pid [17125]
process[bumper2pointcloud-6]: started with pid [17126]
process[robot_state_publisher-7]: started with pid [17127]
process[laserscan_nodelet_manager-8]: started with pid [17134]
process[depthimage_to_laserscan-9]: started with pid [17143]
[ INFO] [1544189992.342004025]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1544189992.342448714]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
```

It stops there and nothing further happend. Turtlebot isn't up.  Normally it should spawn robot and world should be up. This all works when i start on the same pc. When i am trying to start this from home over ssh it stops where i descriped above. Any tips?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21321/starting-gazebo-headless-over-ssh/) by [Baumboon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3848/baumboon/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo needs a display to run. If the remote host has a display server running, you might be able to just set the `DISPLAY` environment variable before launching. Eg. `export DISPLAY=:0`.  Otherwise, you can look into running it headless with a virtual display ([see this answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21170/how-to-run-gazebo-with-a-specific-graphic-card-or-no-graphic-card/?answer=21215#post-id-21215)).

In any case, simply running `gazebo --verbose` on the remote host should provide some information as to why Gazebo isn't running properly.

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2018-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3848/baumboon/) on 2018-12-10**:
so it is not possible to start it headless without display?

Thank u for ur advice !

**Comment by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) on 2018-12-10**:
I believe it is possible to run the server (`gzserver`) without a display but sensors that need rendering (eg. camera) won't work.